# Printing jagged array list in one loop

Tags: java, jagged-arrays

```
int[ ][ ] num=new int[5][ ];
 num[0]=new int[1];
 num[1]=new int[5];
 num[2]=new int[];
 num[3]=new int[3];
```

Can a jagged array be printed in one loop or are two loops needed ?

Comment: 2 dimensions = 2 nested loops.

Comment: That's not an array list, it's an array.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I think the OP means Jagged.

Answer (score 2):

Two loops are needed; one to loop over the array of arrays and one to loop over each nested array and print the appropriate element. You can also simply use [`Arrays.deepToString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) (which uses loops internally):

```
int[][] num = new int[5][];
num[0] = new int[1];
num[1] = new int[5];
num[2] = new int[0];
num[3] = new int[3];

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(num));
```

```
[[0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [], [0, 0, 0], null]
```

Comment: This will not work as `deepToString` works on Integer[] and not int[]. Autoboxing does not work for array primitives

Comment: @arshajii this is a java version dependant argument

Comment: @Jatin *"If an element `e` is an array of a primitive type, it is converted to a string as by invoking the appropriate overloading of `Arrays.toString(e)`. If an element `e` is an array of a reference type, it is converted to a string as by invoking this method recursively."*

Comment: @Cruncher Why do you say that? I believe it'll work in Java 5+ (the `deepToString()` method itself was introduced in Java 5).

Answer (score 1):

```
void printRaggedArray(int[][] ragged) {
    int outer = 0;
    int inner = 0;
    while(outer < ragged.length) {
        if(inner >= ragged[outer].length) {
            inner=0;
            outer++;
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println[outer][inner++];
    }
}
```

This works, but 2 loops is better. This is no faster, in fact it's probably slower.

Comment: Creative. I should say it answers the question! As you say, no one will want to use it, though …

Comment: Lol, I don't remember writing this answer but it's definitely a little cheeky. It's essentially just implementing an inner loop with counters

Comment: @Ole V.V I cleaned it up quite a bit since you liked it

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid writing the inner loop by using `Arrays.toString()`.

```
for(int[] row: num) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

But your code isn't actually faster. Its still using a for loop under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int twoD[][] = new int[4][];
    twoD[0] = new int[1];
    twoD[1] = new int[2];
    twoD[2] = new int[3];
    twoD[3] = new int[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        twoD[i][j] = i + j;
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
        System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```